# Computing an Integration Problem with Limits

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

My Quesion is:

Given that $f_n(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{c l} 
     4n^2x(\frac{1}{n}-x)  & if  & 0 ≤ x ≤\frac{1}{n}  \\
     0 & if &\frac{1}{n}< x ≤ 1
\end{array}\right.$

Compute $ l  i  m_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_n(x)dx$

I get confused when dealing with multiple f(x) values whilst given a certain value of x so if anyone could help compute this integration problem then that will be most kind

Comment: What's the big deal here ? Just integrate $f_n(x)$ and put the limits from $0$ to $\frac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 0):

For any (suitably integrable) $f$ we have
$$\int_a^c f(x)\,dx=\int_a^b f(x)\,dx+\int_b^c f(x)\,dx\ .$$
Apply this to your problem with $a=0$ and $b=\frac1n$ and $c=1$.  You have to calculate two integrals of which the first is pretty easy and the second is even easier.

Comment: but wouldnt you have to apply the limit to $4n^2x(\frac{1}{n}-x)$ first before integrating

Comment: No, your question clearly asks for the limit of the integral, not the integral of the limit.

Comment: when integrating would you get 2/3n for the 1st integration??

Comment: I don't know, I didn't try.  But it's a quadratic so it's sure to be easy.